# SetInterval and SetTimeout not working when trying to load a Partial View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm trying to use `JQuery` to reload a `PartialView` in an `ASP.Net MVC`  application.

My code:

```
<div class="partial">
     @Html.Action("GetRemainingSeats", "Layout")
</div>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            setTimeout(
            $(function () {
                setInterval(function () { $('#partial').load('@Html.Action("GetRemainingSeats", "Layout")'); }, 5000)
            }), 6000);
</script>
```

The partial view is loaded correctly, but immediately after that, it will again execute the action, without waiting for the `setTimeout` function timer to elapse. After that it will stop doing anything.

**Edit:**
Inside the `PartialView` there is a table with shows in a cinema together with how many seats are left for each show. So I want that to update very couple of seconds so the employees can see how many seats are left for a show.

I'm using the timeout and `setinterval` function because on `pageload` the action is called. After that I want it to wait a couple of seconds before starting the interval

Comment: Is `@Html.Action()` a typo (should be `@Url.Action()`)?

Comment: Your question has one thing missing. What do you want to achieve? It will help others to crack down the issue otherwise your code as it seems playing hide and seek in browser.

Comment: Also do tell the need of using `setTimeout` and `setInterval`, together..

Comment: Url.Action() won't do anything, just as using /Layout/GetRemainingSeats won't do anything. The Html.Action() will run, but only once and without waiting for the timeout.

Comment: Of course `Html.Action` will only run once. Its a method that calls a child action and its parsed once only when the view is rendered. You need `Url.Action()`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke when using Url.Action nothing happens, at all. I tried putting an alert in the function, so:

setInterval(function () { $('#partial').load('/Layout/GetRemainingSeats'); **alert("interval called");** }, 4000)

And it does show me the alert every four seconds, but it's not calling the function. Not with /layout/GetRemainingSeats and not with Url.Action("GetRemainingSeats", "Layout")

Comment: Your script has `$('#partial').load(..)` but you don't have an element with `id="partial"`. You do however have an element with `class="partial"`. So one or he other needs to change (and it needs to be `@Url.Action()`, not `@Html.Action()`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you so much!! I'm not sure how I could not have seen it was a class instead of an ID! I would upvote you if I could upvote comments! You just fixed it, thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You script is attempting to load html into an element which does not exist (you only have an element with `class="partial"`, not `id="partial"`. You also need to use `@Url.Action()`, not `@Html.Action()` (which is a helper that call a child action - it does not generate a url which is expected by the `.load()` method. You need to make the following changes

html

```
<div id="partial"> // change this to specify the id attribute
    @Html.Action("GetRemainingSeats", "Layout")
</div>
```

script

```
$(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        $('#partial').load('@Url.Action("GetRemainingSeats", "Layout")'); }, 5000) // use @Url.Action()
    }), 6000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand why you use both timeout and setinterval methods as both work same for first time, if you want to refresh div after 4 sec, stick with setInterval method otherwise if you want to refresh only once, use setTimeout method

```
var wait = setTimeout(
$(function () {
 var s = setInterval(function () {       
         clearInterval(s); // you need to remove the interval if you want to run it once
         $('#partial').load('/Layout/GetRemainingSeats'); 

     }, 4000)
}), 6000);
```

also, you need to change

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")"></script>
```

to

```
 <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")'></script>
```

Comment: I needed the timeout so the partialview wouldn't get loaded twice on page load. I wanted it to wait a couple of seconds before starting the interval.
When I use your code (i removed clearInterval) It won't call the action again and when I use an @Html.Action it will only call the action once and then stop the interval.